# How to prove that $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{1+n^{2}x^{2}}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I am having trouble verifying continuity. This seems like a very simple problem but I am not sure if my approach is correct:

To prove that $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{1+n^{2}x^{2}}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, I first notice that $1+n^{2}x^{2}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. Then because the inverse is also continuous, I claim that $f_n(x)$ is continuous also since the denominator can never be zero. . However, I don't know if the above argument can apply to *sequences* of functions as well or just functions. Thank you!

Comment: It seems that you're proving that the function $f_n$ defined by the given formula is continuous. In that case, the fact that it's an element of some sequence is irrelevant.

Comment: You are right, the argument can apply to sequences of functions, because each element of the sequence is a function itself!

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks!!

Comment: It might be good to note that the limit of this sequence is not continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| =|{1 \over 1+ n^2 x^2 } - {1 \over 1+ n^2 y^2 }| = n^2| {x^2-y^2  \over (1+n^2 x^2)(1+n^2 y^2)} | \le n^2 |x-y||x+y| \le 2 n^2 |x-y|$.
Hence $f_n$ is Lipschitz continuous on $[0,1]$.